# Elasticsearch create index errors out

Tags: post, elasticsearch, indexing

I am very new to Elasticsearch.Using ES 5.1.1, I am trying to create the following simple index:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/user" -d'
{
  "mappings": {
    "post": {
      "properties": {
        "first_name": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "last_name": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "birth_date": {
          "type": "date"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

But I am getting an HTTP 400 with the following error message:

```
No handler found for uri [/user] and method [POST]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since ES 5, you [must use PUT](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking_50_rest_api_changes.html#_index_creation_endpoint_only_accepts_literal_put_literal) instead of POST when creating new indices:

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/user" -d'
{
  "mappings": {
    "post": {
      "properties": {
        "first_name": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "last_name": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "birth_date": {
          "type": "date"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Comment: That was it, Thank U so much for the prompt reply!